# Unknown database type enum requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySQL57Platform may not support it

Tags: doctrine-orm

I'm getting the following error while running,

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate

[Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.


  [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
  Unknown database type enum requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySQL57Platform may not support it.


doctrine:schema:validate [--skip-mapping] [--skip-sync] [--em [EM]] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command>.
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `mapping_types` in your configuration:

```
#config/packages/doctrine.yaml doctrine
dbal:
    types:
        myenum: App\DBAL\MyEnumType
    mapping_types:
        enum: string # <- this is what you need!
```

and in your entity class:

```
class Page {
    ...
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="myenum")
     */
    protected $type;
    ...

}
```

Link to documentation how to prepare your own Mapping Type
[doctrine2-mapping-types](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/mysql-enums.html#solution-2-defining-a-type)